# how to upgrade wordpress's plugin to version five?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a plugin that doesnt have any problem with version 4 of wordpress but when I add it to version 5 it wont be shown in the list of plugins.
I need to know how to make this plugin works in version 5 as it does in older versions.
Is there any changes I must apply?

Comment: Which plugin are u talking about? how do you update the plugin? are you sure they just didn't change the plugin name so it's somewhere else on the list?

Comment: yes there is no update for this plugin because my friends made this plugin